# Cumulative Columns Based on a Rule in R

Tags: r

I have an incremental development data. Each Dev# columns shows individual payments of the ClaimNo.

```
ClaimNo<-c("3333","11111","01010","15060")
AccidentPeriod <- c(0,3,1,2)
Information<-c("Infor","Infor","Infor","Infor")
Dev0<-c(100,40,50,0)
Dev1<-c(0,0,100,15)
Dev2<-c(50,0,0,0)
Dev3<-c(0,0,0,0)

IncrementalData<-data.frame(ClaimNo,AccidentPeriod,Information,Dev0,Dev1,Dev2,Dev3)
```

[image]

I need to obtain make it cumulative. Summing the columns should stop at the diagonal. For example we know  that we have 4 development periods. When the claim's AccidentPeriod is 2, summing should stop at Dev2 because AccidentPeriod + Dev# cannot exceed 3(*we start from 0*).

```
If the AccidentPeriod is 0, summing of Dev# should stop at 3
If the AccidentPeriod is 2, summing of Dev# should stop at 1
If the AccidentPeriod is 1, summing of Dev# should stop  at 2
```

I can write ifelse function each cumulative columns in order to get this cumulative data. But there are too many columns. There should be a short way..

This is What I need.

[image]

If you want to write this on VBA:

```
DevCum_0=Dev0
for a=1 to 3
b=a-1
DevCum_a=Deva+DevCum_b
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear to mean what the rules exactly is. But I would try a work with a tall format of the data. I.e .try `IncrementalData %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("Dev"))` and work with that format of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below with `apply`

```
indsDev <- grep("^Dev",names(IncrementalData))
dfout <- cbind(
    IncrementalData[-indsDev],
    t(apply(
        IncrementalData,
        1,
        function(x) {
            x[min(indsDev):(max(indsDev) - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[indsDev]), length(indsDev) - as.numeric(x[2]))
            `class<-`(x[indsDev], "numeric")
        }
    ))
)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  ClaimNo AccidentPeriod Information Dev0 Dev1 Dev2 Dev3
1    3333              0       Infor  100  100  150  150
2   11111              3       Infor   40    0    0    0
3   01010              1       Infor   50  150  150    0
4   15060              2       Infor    0   15    0    0
```

Comment: In my case I have 46 columns and Dev values start from 7th column. If I revise your I wrote:

`PAID_5 <- cbind(
  PAID_4[1:6],
  t(apply(
    PAID_4,
    1,
    function(x) {
      x[7:(46 - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[-(1:6)]), 7 - as.numeric(x[2]))
      `class<-`(x[-(1:6)], "numeric")
    }
  ))
)
`

#After I ran the query I got this Warning.

`Error in x[7:(46 - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[-(1:6)]), 7 - as.numeric(x[2])) : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
In`

Comment: @SeqenenreTao I guess you should use `head(cumsum(x[-(1:6)]), 40 - as.numeric(x[2]))`

Comment: `PAID_5 <- cbind(
  PAID_4[1:6],
  t(apply(
    PAID_4,
    1,
    function(x) {
      x[7:(46 - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[-(1:6)]), 40 - as.numeric(x[2]))
      `class<-`(x[-(1:6)], "numeric")
    }
  ))
)`

#Got same warning message

##'Error in x[7:(46 - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[-(1:6)]), 40 -  : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts'

Comment: @SeqenenreTao What is the range of in `AccidentPeriod`? 0 to 39?

Comment: Yes AccdientPeriod range is 0 to 39 in 2.5mio rows data.

Comment: @SeqenenreTao Could you post a minimal reproducible example of your real data `PAID_4`, e.g.,`dput(head(PAID_4))`? I am not able to see what happens by being told the errors only

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error. Just I changed the first rows. Because my column names are Dev0, Dev1, Dev2 instead of 0,1,2.. 

So I changed just the first row of your query. 

'indsDev <- 7:40
dfout <- cbind(
  PAID_4[-indsDev],
  t(apply(
    PAID_4,
    1,
    function(x) {
      x[min(indsDev):(max(indsDev) - as.numeric(x[2]))] <- head(cumsum(x[indsDev]), length(indsDev) - as.numeric(x[2]))
      `class<-`(x[indsDev], "numeric")
    }
  ))
)'

Comment: @SeqenenreTao Did you tried the accepted answer on your real data? Without your real data, it is not possible to know where is the problem...

Comment: I know but how can I share this? As I said before the data is quite big. Your query is working with an example but not worked with my big data.

Comment: @SeqenenreTao Use `dput(head(PAID_4),4)` and copy its output and paste in your post

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` :

```
cols <- grep('Dev', names(IncrementalData), value = TRUE)
last_col <- length(cols) + 1

IncrementalData[cols] <- t(apply(IncrementalData[c('AccidentPeriod', cols)], 1, 
   function(x) {
         if(x[1] == 0) cumsum(x[2:last_col])
         else if(x[1] == 1) c(cumsum(x[2:4]), x[5:last_col])
         else if(x[1] == 2) x[2:last_col]
         else if(x[1] == 3) c(cumsum(x[2:3]), x[4:last_col])
}))

#  ClaimNo AccidentPeriod Information Dev0 Dev1 Dev2 Dev3
#1    3333              0       Infor  100  100  100  100
#2   11111              3       Infor   40   40    0    0
#3   01010              1       Infor   50  150  150    0
#4   15060              2       Infor    0   15    0    0
```